# How to let pacman notice the ruby installed by rbenv?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, ruby, gvim

I use `rbenv` to manage `ruby` versions.

I want to install `gvim` on my ArchLinux and one of it's dependency is `ruby`.

I'm already use `rbenv` to install the version 2.0.0-p247 of ruby as root user and set `rbenv global 2.0.0-p247`,but when I try `sudo pacman -S gvim`, `pacman` still install the package `ruby-2.0.0_p247-1`.

How can I let `pacman` notice the `ruby` installed by `rbenv` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. However, you can trick pacman into thinking you have (there are two ways to do this).

1. Simply pass the `--dbonly` option:

   ```
   pacman -S --dbonly ruby
   ```

   This will commit the transaction to the database (make a record of the install), but not actually download or install any packages.

   If you want, you could also pass `--asdeps` to mark it as a dependency.

   Also to note: ruby may get installed for real on upgrade. I'm not sure. You may want to consider locking the version (it's ok because it's not really installed or critical, but normally you should not do this).
2. Make `rbenv` provide `ruby`. You can do this by putting the following line in the `rbenv` PKGBUILD:

   ```
   provides=('ruby')
   ```

   After doing this, run `makepkg` again and reinstall the package with `pacman -U foobar.pkg.tar.xz`.

   You may have to mess with the version of this. See the [wiki page on PKGBUILDS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD#provides).

Comment: Can rvm be used here as well, or not? I know you can install it as the system level ruby.

Comment: @slm looks like rvm is neither in the official repos nor the AUR. you can use it, though, if you're ok with no package manager integration.

Comment: Yeah rvm isn't ever in any packages, it's a shell script, so it's typically not distributed that way to my knowledge. Just wondering on archLinux if that was an apt way to go.

Comment: the only difference is that if you use `rbenv` you can use method two (that i just added), because there's a package for it, but if you use `rvm` you can only do method 1.